# UIKit layout issues on iPhone 5 vs simulator

Tags: iphone, user-interface, uikit, ios6

When I run my iOS app in the simulator (iOS 6, 4 inch screen) the app doesn't try to fill the entire screen. It just runs with the black band above and below the 480 height app. However when I run the app on my iPhone 5 it tries to run full-screen.

I appreciate the flexibility of UIKit that makes this possible. However the UI for this app (which I didn't create) wasn't designed so well. Hence UIKit's automatic adjustments on the 4-inch screen mess things up pretty badly. So I'd like to turn this "auto-adjust" feature off for the moment so the app is useable while I take time to actually fix the layout for the larger screen.

**How can I prevent a UIKit-based iOS app from trying to run full-screen on the iPhone 5?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set a splash screen for 4 inch? If so, remove it and then Product->clean your project. Also delete the app off of your iPhone 5 before running it again.